# Updating the column based on Unique value in one col & max repeated values in another col

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert the data based on the max repeated values.

1. I have truck numbers in col A and "Truck types" in column in B col.
2. For each unique truck number, the truck type should be same.(This is the expected result)
3. This can be achieved, by counting the maximum no. of truck types for the unique "truck no", and that cell to be updated with the Max. repeated "Truck type".
4. If there is equal no. of "Truck types" are available, It should be updated with the first available truck type.

Like this, there are thousands of rows to be updated. This can be
better understand by seeing the attached image.

I have attached the image & expected result is in the column C.

I have googled a lot, but I was unable to find the relevant solution.
Please help.

[image]

Comment: Are the `Vehicle No` sorted like in the picture?

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld  Hai Ron, I am using excel 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not say anything...

Please, test the next code. It works with assumption that the columns are sorted as we can see in the picture. It is very fast, since the result is put in an array and dropped on the sheet at once:

```
Sub findMaxCountVehType_Array()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, rngVeh As Range, rngTemp As Range, arrFin As Variant
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, w As Long, count As Long, maxCount As Long, ar As Long, maxStr As String

   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet
   lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   Set rngVeh = sh.Range("A2:C" & lastRow)
   ReDim arrFin(1 To lastRow, 1 To 1)
   arrFin(1, 1) = "Result": ar = 1

   For i = 2 To lastRow
        If sh.Range("A" & i).Value = sh.Range("A" & i + 1).Value Then
            For j = i To j + 1000 'create a range of type cells for the same vehicle no
                If sh.Range("A" & j).Value = sh.Range("A" & i).Value Then
                    If rngTemp Is Nothing Then
                        Set rngTemp = sh.Range("B" & j)
                    Else
                        Set rngTemp = Union(rngTemp, sh.Range("B" & j))
                    End If
                Else
                  Exit For
                End If
            Next j
            If rngTemp Is Nothing Then
               ar = ar + 1: arrFin(ar, 1) = sh.Range("B" & i)
            Else
                For w = 1 To rngTemp.Cells.count 'determine the max occurrences string
                    count = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngTemp, rngTemp.Cells(w, 1).Value)
                    If count > maxCount Then maxCount = count: maxStr = rngTemp.Cells(w, 1).Value
                Next
                For w = 1 To rngTemp.Cells.count
                    ar = ar + 1: arrFin(ar, 1) = maxStr    'fill the max count in the array
                Next
            End If
            Set rngTemp = Nothing: maxCount = 0: count = 0 'reinitialize variables
            i = i + w - 2 'move the iteration to the following vehicle
        Else
            ar = ar + 1: arrFin(ar, 1) = sh.Range("B" & i)
        End If
   Next i
   'drop the result array at once
    sh.Range("C1").Resize(UBound(arrFin, 1), UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value = arrFin
End Sub
```

Comment: The code is working perfectly.You are amazing "FaneDuru". Thank you very much for your time to write this tricky code. I was amazed how you think to write this code!

Comment: @Srinivas Rao Gampala: Glad I could help! But we here, when somebody post a code answering the question, we tick the code left side check box, making it **accepted answer**. In this way somebody else searching for something similar will know that the code worked as needed...

Comment: Both answers are equally Accepted

Comment: @Srinivas Rao Gampala: No problem with me. When I placed the comment I did not see an accepted answer. Anyhow, my answer came with 5 hours before the second one after I wait for you to answer my question, but this does not mean that the second could not be better... Glad you found at least a solution....

Comment: @Srinivas Rao Gampala: If available time and interest to check, please test the updated answer (for many records) and see which code is faster... Do not forget to refresh the page, in order to take the updated code, before copying it.

Comment: Hello Fane, Your updated Array code is blazing fast. You are really great & thanks for your effort!! Taken 10 seconds to execute the code on 2 lakhs of rows.

Comment: @Srinivas Rao Gampala: Eight month to understand that, it is a real record.:) I am only asking myself how fast can be the code you marked as **accepted answer**... If you do not know, you can mark the accepted answer whenever you want. It is not a matter of gaining notoriety. I have extra 1000 points from that time and I do not care about it. It is only a matter of principle.

Comment: Hello Fane, I am really sorry for replying to your updated post. I rarely visit this site as I am a beginner. But I know your efforts to understand the requirement, think & write the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VBA routine that uses:

- A class object which has

  - key:= Vehicle number
  - item:= dictionary of associated vehicle types

    - key:= vehicle type
    - item:= count of the vehicle types

After collecting the information, we merely need to cycle through the dictionary and extract, for any given vehicle ID, the vehicle type that has the largest count.

This routine, since it works entirely with VBA arrays, should run pretty fast, even with large amounts of data.

Also, with this method, no sorting is required.

- ASSUMES the data starts in cell `A1` (could be changed if necessary)
- ASSUMES results are as you show with `Desired Result` in column C

**Be sure to set a reference (Tools/References) to Microsoft Scripting Runtime**

#### Class Module  *(rename this module `cVehicle`)*

```
Option Explicit
Private pVehicleType As String
Private pVehicleTypes As Dictionary

Public Property Get VehicleType() As String
    VehicleType = pVehicleType
End Property
Public Property Let VehicleType(Value As String)
    pVehicleType = Value
End Property

Public Property Get VehicleTypes() As Dictionary
    Set VehicleTypes = pVehicleTypes
End Property
Public Function addVehicleTypesItem(Value)
    If pVehicleTypes.Exists(Value) Then
        pVehicleTypes(Value) = pVehicleTypes(Value) + 1
    Else
        pVehicleTypes.Add Key:=Value, Item:=1
    End If
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pVehicleTypes = New Dictionary
        pVehicleTypes.CompareMode = TextCompare
    
End Sub
```

#### Regular Module

```
'Set Reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Option Explicit
Sub vehicle()
    Dim dV As Dictionary, cV As cVehicle
    Dim wsData As Worksheet, vData As Variant, rRes As Range
    Dim V As Variant, I As Long, sKey As String, cKey As String, Cnt As Long
    
'set data worksheet
'read data into vba array
Set wsData = Worksheets("Sheet3")
With wsData
    'add extra column for the "desired results"
    vData = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=3)
    Set rRes = .Cells(1, 1)
End With

'loop through the data and count the types
'no sorting necessary
Set dV = New Dictionary
For I = 2 To UBound(vData, 1)
    Set cV = New cVehicle
    With cV
        sKey = vData(I, 1)
        .VehicleType = vData(I, 2)
        If Not dV.Exists(sKey) Then
            .addVehicleTypesItem .VehicleType
            dV.Add sKey, cV
        Else
            dV(sKey).addVehicleTypesItem .VehicleType
        End If
    End With
Next I

'Output the data
I = 1
'Header
vData(I, 3) = "Desired Result"

'Data
For I = 2 To UBound(vData, 1)
    sKey = vData(I, 1)
    With dV(sKey)
    
        'which type has the highest count
        Cnt = 0
        For Each V In .VehicleTypes.Keys
            If .VehicleTypes(V) > Cnt Then
                Cnt = .VehicleTypes(V)
                cKey = V
            End If
        Next V
        vData(I, 3) = cKey
    End With
Next I
            
'write the results
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vData, 1), UBound(vData, 2))

rRes = vData

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hai Ron Rosenfeld, Firstly I must thank you for spending this much time for me to write this tricky code. You are really genius!. Even I did not understand how you written the code by using class module & normal module. It worked blazing fast. I have tested this code on about 2 lakhs+ of rows, given the required result in about 15 seconds only. I was amazed. Thank you very much again!